# JSONArray not supported before Android API 19

Tags: java, android, json

I need to send data using a JSONArray, which is not available beore android api level 19. The Json object is like -

```
myJob = {"data1":['a','b','c'],
      "data2":[1,2,3]
     }
```

What should I use for previous API levels?

Comment: what is not available before api level 19?

Comment: org.json.JSONArray is available from API level 1(one).

Comment: [api ref link](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Comment: Which kind of error do you get? Can you elaborate your question with some code or logcat.

Comment: i think only the remove() function is only available for API 19 and above

Answer (score 3):

I presume MR. Gupta were referring to the compilation error when he was trying to create JSONArray this way:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.getJSONArray("results"));
```

Android Studio gives this hint:

*Call requires API level 19 (current minimum is <19)*

Here is one of the right ways to construct JSONArray:

```
JSONArray resultsJsonArr = moviesJsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Json Object and Json Array below API 19 Also.

```
JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject();
 data1.put("id", "2");
 data1.put("name", "John");
JSONObject data2 = new JSONObject();
 data2.put("id", "2");
 data2.put("name", "John");

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();// this is Json Array

jsonArray.put(data1);
jsonArray.put(data2);
```

Note: It look like you Json is not proper. Please check and varify it with online json validator http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray = new JSONArray(stringJsonArray); //not avail below api 19.

To use it, there is a trick.

```
String str = "[1,2,3,4]"; //example string.

String json = "{\"data\":" + str + "}";  //this is trick.

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("data");
```