# Reading JSON file in Android with API issue

Tags: java, android, json

i am new to **Android**. i have a working **JSON** reading code in **JAVA** as below. which save the file as a string and then create the **JSON array** out of it. i want to do the same in android but it says the error(shown below)

```
 String jsonInput = new Scanner(new File("c:\\patient.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonInput);
 System.out.println("LENGTH IS____"+ja.length());
 String[][] table = new String[ja.length()][4];
 for(int y=0;y<ja.length();y++)
  {
      JSONObject jb = ja.getJSONObject(y);
      System.out.println(jb.length());
      String p=jb.getString("priority");
      String r=jb.getString("rule_body");
      String c=jb.getString("cons");
      String b=jb.getString("boolean");
      System.out.println("Priority: "+p+"- Rule Body: "+r+"- Consequence: "+c+"- flag: "+b);
      table[y][0]=p;
      table[y][1]=r;
      table[y][2]=c;
      table[y][3]=b;


  }
```

which is working fine as intended. I want to do the same in Android(With the text file copied to assets folder) but i get the error that

```
Call require API 19 and the MIN is 8
```

i need a help here that how do i sort this out in the working API. I am trying to get the arrays from the JSON file, as i see here most of the example are for JSON objects. The question posted [JSONArray not supported before Android API 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647476/jsonarray-not-supported-before-android-api-19) has not mentioned clearly the problem as i stated.

```
InputStream json= getAssets().open("patient.txt");
JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(json);
System.out.println("LENGTH IS____"+ja.length());
String[][] table = new String[ja.length()][4];
```

Structure of JSON is

```
[{"priority":"1","rule_body":"person(?x),patientid(?y),hasid(?x,?y)","cons":"patient(?x)","boolean":"1"},{"priority":"2","rule_body":"patient(?x),hasbp(?x,high)","cons":"hassituation(?x,emergency)","boolean":"1"},{"priority":"3","rule_body":"patient(?x),hassituation(?x,emergency)","cons":"calldr(emergency)","boolean":"1"},{"priority":"4","rule_body":"patient(?x),calldr(emergency)","cons":"calling_in_dr(emergency)","boolean":"1"},{"priority":"5","rule_body":"patient(?x),calling_in_dr(emergency)","cons":"cured(?x)","boolean":"1"}]
```

encoded using php encode method.

Comment: i want to test it on my device which is API 16

Comment: Because you are using something which requre your projects minimun sdk on 19  not below 19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONArray not supported before Android API 19](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647476/jsonarray-not-supported-before-android-api-19)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your code with this. this will work fine with lower API too. you are passing `InputStream` Object as a argument instead you should pass `String`.

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("patient.txt");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
System.out.println("LENGTH IS____"+ ja.length());
String[][] table = new String[ja.length()][4];
```

Comment: you can pass `JSONArray` or `JSONObject` objects starting from API level 19. thats why it was giving you that error

Comment: Well now u solved it, so ill move ahead with rest thanks @Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Here is Proper way to get JsonArray

```
JSONArray resultArray = obj.getJSONArray("results");
```